# Parameter formatting in VBA prompting a 'Type mismatch' error at runtime?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm adapting some inherited MS Access VBA code (below) so I realise there are better ways to manage this but, that said, what I've done should do the job.  I can can see that there should probably be a closing parenthesis at the end of this SQL string, so there is something amiss but I can't see it!  When I try to execute this line of code I get a 'Type mismatch' error on 'openrecordset', this leads me to believe there is something wrong in the way the query parameters are syntaxed, can anyone help (preferably with a tweak rather than a rewrite).  Many thanks in advance.

```
Set Owners = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT RES_LoginRef.UserID_USE_REF, 
RES_LoginRef.ResSysID, RES_LoginRef.UserID, AGENTS.WIN_Username, 
RES_LoginRef.EmploymentID, RES_LoginRef.RL_IncludeFrom, 
RES_LoginRef.RL_IncludeTo
 FROM AGENTS INNER JOIN (RES_LoginRef INNER JOIN EMP_HISTORY ON 
RES_LoginRef.EmploymentID = EMP_HISTORY.EmploymentID) ON AGENTS.AgentID = 
EMP_HISTORY.AgentID WHERE (((RES_LoginRef.ResSysID)=1) AND 
((RES_LoginRef.RL_IncludeFrom<=#" & Format([Forms]![Parameters]! 
[ProcessDate], 
"mm/dd/yy")) & "# AND ((RES_LoginRef.RL_IncludeTo>=#" & Format([Forms]!
[Parameters]![ProcessDate], "mm/dd/yy") & "# Or RES_LoginRef.RL_IncludeTo Is 
Null);"
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Very many thanks Andre.  I believe I have confirmed my suspicion that the date parameter syntax is at fault but my knowledge falls short of being able to fix it...can anyone else see where I've gone wrong?  Thx.

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the link Andre gave you (`strSQL = "SELECT ..."` etc.)?  How does Access respond when you test that SQL statement as a new query in the Access query designer?

Comment: AFAIK, nothing wrong with date parameter syntax - works for me with and without Format() function. Assuming fields are date/time type.

Comment: Hi HansUp - I have followed Andre's advise and pasted the VBA into the query builder but the query throws an error as the VBA has special characters that won't allow it to run.  If I remove this and add the parameters in the query builder it work fine but that doesn't resolve my date format syntax issue :-(

Comment: Thanks June7 - its looks about right to me but there's obviously something I'm missing!